# Efficient way to return counts and averages without joining together multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

In my PostgreSQL 14.8 database I have a table named `orders` that looks as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
  user_id int
, order_id int
, order_date date
, quantity int
, revenue float
, product text
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(1, 1, '2021-03-05', 1, 15, 'books'),
(1, 2, '2022-03-07', 1, 3, 'music'),
(1, 3, '2022-06-15', 1, 900, 'travel'),
(1, 4, '2021-11-17', 2, 25, 'books'),
(2, 5, '2022-08-03', 2, 32, 'books'),
(2, 6, '2021-04-12', 2, 4, 'music'),
(2, 7, '2021-06-29', 3, 9, 'books'),
(2, 8, '2022-11-03', 1, 8, 'music'),
(3, 9, '2022-11-07', 1, 575, 'food'),
(3, 10, '2022-11-20', 2, 95, 'food'),
(3, 11, '2022-11-20', 1, 95, 'food'),
(4, 12, '2022-11-20', 2, 95, 'books'),
(4, 13, '2022-11-21', 1, 95, 'food'),
(4, 14, '2022-11-23', 4, 17, 'books'),
(5, 15, '2022-11-20', 1, 95, 'food'),
(5, 16, '2022-11-25', 2, 95, 'books'),
(5, 17, '2022-11-29', 1, 95, 'food');
```

See SQL fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3dc69/1

I would like to get the following:

Among customers who **first purchased a book** (first according to `order_date`) as a `product` (in this case, customer IDs 1 and 4), I would like to get:

A) the average `quantity` of books that this cohort purchased (in this case, 2.25, which is the average of 1, 2, 2, and 4), and;

B) the total `revenue` of each of these purchases (in this case, 152).

I tried to use several CTEs to accomplish this.  Here is my attempt:

```sql
WITH all_orders AS (
  SELECT
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.user_id ORDER BY o.order_date) AS row_num
  FROM
    orders o
  ),

  first_product_is_books AS (
  SELECT
      DISTINCT(user_id) AS usr_id
  FROM
    all_orders
  WHERE product = 'books' AND row_num = 1
  ),

  temp_results AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    all_orders ao
  JOIN
    first_product_is_books AS fp
  ON ao.user_id = fp.usr_id
  )

  SELECT
    avg(quantity)
    , sum(revenue)
  FROM
    temp_results tr
  WHERE
     tr.product = 'books'
```

See fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3dc69/1

This works on a toy dataset, but not on the production dataset, where the table is about 400,000 records.  I think this query is hacky and not really optimized. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: `Among customers who first purchased a book as a product (in this case, customer IDs 1 and 4),` - I don't understand - why doesn't customer 2 (who has two purchases also) get included? What is it that distinguishes 1 and 2?

Comment: @Vérace - customer 2 did not purchase books first.  He/she first purchased music on April 12, 2021 (the date are out of order).

Answer (score 1):

Simpler with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT avg(o.quantity) AS avg_quantity
     , sum(o.revenue)  AS total_revenue
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
          user_id, product
   FROM   orders
   ORDER  BY user_id, order_date
   ) init
JOIN   orders o USING (user_id, product)
WHERE  init.product = 'books';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5gfIaYEm)

Which query style is the most efficient primarily depends on cardinalities. How many rows total, how many users, how many orders for books, how many initial orders with books, avg row size, avg size of `product`.

Can be simpler and faster if there is also a table `users` holding one row per relevant `user_id`.

And you need an index to support the query. Ideally, on `(user_id, order_date, product)`. Again, the best index depends on above mentioned undisclosed details.

And `(user_id, order_date)` must be unique, or there is ambiguity.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: I did a performnce analysis of the three queries proposed [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QssN_Qfo) -  I would be interested in any comments you may have on the fiddle - in particular my choice of PK. Yours is consistently the fastest - but I realise that tests done on small datasets are not necessarily the most reliable.

Comment: @Vérace: Sorry, not much time now. Yes, this needs to be tested on big (realistic) data sets. Like I elaborated above, much depends on cardinalities. `DISTINCT ON` is often the winner with few rows per group. Some important improvements in pg 16 ...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
with order_cte as 
(
  SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by user_id order by order_date) as row_num
  from orders
 )
 
 SELECT
 AVG(QUANTITY)AVG_QUANTITY
 , SUM(REVENUE)TOTAL_REV
 FROM ORDERS
 WHERE PRODUCT = 'books'
   and USER_ID IN (
                   SELECT
                    USER_ID
                     FROM ORDER_CTE
                    WHERE PRODUCT = 'books'
                      AND ROW_NUM = 1
                 )
```

Comment: This query appears to work quite well, but is consistently slower than @ErwinBrandstetter's - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QssN_Qfo) (although not by much). I would be interested in any comments you may have on the fiddle - in particular the choice of PK. I realise that tests done on small datasets are not necessarily the most reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This version of your query is much easier to read.

```
WITH first_orders AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        user_id, 
        FIRST_VALUE(product) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date) as first_product
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY user_id, order_date, product
)

SELECT 
    AVG(o.quantity) AS avg_quantity, 
    SUM(o.revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM orders o
JOIN first_orders fo
ON o.user_id = fo.user_id
WHERE fo.first_product = 'books' AND o.product = 'books';
```

Comment: Your query is also significantly slower than @ErwinBrandstetter's - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QssN_Qfo). I realise that tests done on small datasets are not necessarily the most reliable. I would be interested in any comments you may have on the fiddle - in particular the choice of PK.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter has the best answer here regarding performance. I dont think any other input I have would improve upon what has already been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's logic is flawed (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/t-gZVhzs))!

```
> A) the average quantity of books that this cohort purchased (in this
> case, 2.25, which is the average of 1, 2, 2, and 4), and;
> 
> B) the total revenue of each of these purchases (in this case, 152).
```

You want the average quantity of books purchased over the **two** books of the **two** users (1 & 4), but the **total** revenue from the four purchases is **not** 152, but 323!

This is calculated by (see table population in the fiddle)

- user_1 = (1 x 15) + (2 x 25) = 15 + 50 = 65
- user_2 = (2 x 95) + (4 x 17) = 190 + 68 = 258
- 65 + 258 = 323

**323** is the correct total for the total revenue for the two users.

As an aside, 152 = 15 + 25 + 95 + 17, i.e. no account has been taken of quantities in the calculation!

The table was constructed and populated as per your data.

And then, I ran the following SQL:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    user_id,   -- some of these fields are not necessary
    product,   -- they just help in getting the full picture.
    order_date,
    SUM(revenue * quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product)     AS rev,
    AVG(quantity)  OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product) AS avg_qty,
    ROW_NUMBER()            OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, order_date) AS rn
  FROM 
    orders
  ORDER BY user_id, order_date
)
SELECT 
  SUM(rev)  AS tot_rev,
  ROUND(AVG(avg_qty), 2) AS avg_q
FROM 
  cte
WHERE 
  product = 'books' AND rn = 1;
```

Result:

```
tot_rev     avg_q
323     2.25
```

Et voilà - the correct answer!

Comment: OP posted expected output of 152 leading to the assumption that the revenue column reflects the total of the sale. When folks post to SO they generally leave out superfluous columns like unit price in this instance. Unless you ask a clarifying question to the OP I think the answer you have provided is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert - hmmm... and OP's have never been known to be wrong? If the OP wants the average quantity of **all** the books, then I believe that it is reasonable to assume that they also want the total revenue from **all** books - it's the only thing that makes sense - at least to me!

Comment: What if the OP is correct?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert - then they are free to ignore my answer - or even downvote it if they so wish - but, as far as I'm concerned, if you take the average quantity over all of the books and the total revenue only for a subset of them, then you are mixing apples and oranges!

Comment: If you are correct then OP should rethink the name of the column. Definition of revenue: "[Revenue is the money generated from normal business operations, calculated as the average sales price times the number of units sold](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/revenue.asp)".

Comment: @ChrisAlbert - Maybe you're right, maybe I am - we'll let the OP decide?